# A Good Problem and Solutions Book for Many Body Physics

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, education, many-body

I am looking for a good problems and solutions book for many body physics. I tried looking online for some but could not find much. Here are the topics I am looking for:

Quantum fields

Second quantization

Applications of second quantization: Jellium model, Tight binding model, Mott Hubbard transition and Spin models of Mott insulator, Interacting fermions in 1D, Quantum spin chain

Feynman path integral

Functional field integral

Green's function at zero temperature and finite temperature (Matsubara formalism)

Perturbation Theory

Plasma theory of interacting electron gas

Bose-Einstein condensation and superfluidity

Superconductivity & BCS Theory

Currently, I am using the book *Condensed Matter Field Theory*, which does have some (i.e. 4 to 8) end-of-chapter problems and solutions, but the number of exercises is not large. I found a problem book on Quantum Field Theory by Voja Radovanovi ́c which contains some important topic such as Green's functions and re-normalization but is missing the other topics.

Can anyone suggest a good problem and solutions book? By "good" I mean that the book contains at least Quantum fields to Green's Function in the above list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a problems and solutions (solutions in the back of the book) for topics 2,3,6, and 7

*Theoretical Physics 9:

Fundamentals of Many-body Physics

Second Edition*

**Author: Wolfgang Nolting**

Here is the book's structure:

Chapter 1 is on  Second Quantisation

Chapter 2 is many body systems models

Chapter 3 is on Green's functions

Chapter 4 is on Interacting Particles

Chapter 5 and 6 are on Perturbation Theory (T = 0, and T = finite)

Each chapter ends with self examination questions and answers are in the end of the book. Preceding the exercises are thorough descriptions of the topics, starting with preliminary ideas.

Comment: This text exists (in English at least) as a stand-alone book by Springer.